# Passing C# structures to C++/CLI

Tags: c#, c++, interop, c++-cli

What is the best online guide/tutorial to start with interop using C# and C++/CLI ? I'm looking for a good guide in passing structures made in C# to C++/CLI. Many of the tutorials I have seen do not cover passing custom structures made in C# to C++/CLI.
Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) didn't help? There's a whole section on marshalling structs.

Comment: @nneonneo, at a glance I did not see anything in here about passing structs from C# to C++, which is what the OP is asking. It's a common mistake as mostly it's done the other way round to allow .NET to call unmanaged code, however calling managed code from an unmanaged environment sounds like it may be more tricky, if not, impossible.

Comment: Uh, that's what marshalling usually means -- turning managed objects into unmanaged objects. You need to be able to convert structs both ways for effective interop, even when calling unmanaged code from managed code.

Comment: My understanding of C++/CLI is that it is a C++ based language (as it does not use strict C++ syntax) for creating managed applications. Therefore, you "should" be able to reference your C# struct directly from C++/CLI. In terms of calling a C# struct from traditional C++ (unmanaged)...I don't know that this is possible, as the unmanaged code would need to know how to read and marshal a struct from a .NET assembly.

Comment: Very unclear why this is a problem.  Just add a reference to the C# assembly that declares the struct.  Nothing special is needed.  Don't use the hat, it is a value type.

Comment: @nneonneo, Yes I get that, but, say for example I was writing an old fashioned, real mode DOS application in Borland Turbo C++....you're saying there "should" be a mechanism for me to be able to marshal a C# struct from my old school C++ application? I'm sure there must be limitations here?

Comment: But the question isn't about that - it's very specifically about C++/CLI.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy, I know...as I have already stated above. I was trying to make the distinction between C++/CLI and traditional C++ so that the OP might be clearer on exactly why it is easy to use C# structs from C++/CLI, but not from C++

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason you don't find many tutorials is that there is really nothing to it. You pass the managed structure from C# to C++/CLI the same way as you would to another C# class/method

say you had structure in C#:

```
public struct TheStruct
{
  public int i;
  public String str;
}
```

You would write a method in C++/CLI that looked like this:

```
// *.h
void PassStruct(TheStruct ^myStruct); 


// *.cpp
void classnamegoeshere::PassStruct(TheStruct ^myStruct)
{
   int j = myStrict->i;
   String ^localStr = myStruct->str;
}
```

So, a couple of notes...

1. you need to make sure you put the using statement in your C++/CLI
   code to get your C# reference
2. Include the C# assembly (that defines the struct) in the C++/CLI reference list)
3. Managed objects always use the ^ pointer notation (vs. *)
4. To use methods or member use standard pointer notation ( -> )
5. You need to be careful not to create circular references, so you may want to have TheStruct defined in C++/CLI in which case it would
   look like:

   public ref struct TheStruct
   {
     public:
       int i;
       String ^str;
   }

Easy enought?

Comment: hmm that sounds easy enough. I was going the route of marshaling the C# structure to a pointer and passing that into C++/CLI... but that got complicated. Thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @David I would like to give you +1 but your current reputation says exactly 1337 and I don't want to be the one messing around with that..